# DataTable devuelve 0 Rows

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-forms

Estoy realizando un proyecto para la universidad, en el cual se pide usar SQL Server y WindowsForms, y estoy teniendo un problema con esta ventana:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en cada DataGridView debería mostrar los registros de Habitaciones y clientes respectivamente, sin embargo no consigo lograr que se muestren los datos, he verificado que haya registros en las tablas que intento acceder, he probado enviar los datos a otros Gridview de otras ventanas, y si funcionan, este es el codigo con el cual se carga la ventana.

```
public EnlaceDB linker = new EnlaceDB();
private void Reservaciones_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            NombreCli_Reserv_LBL.Text = "";
            HotelNomb_Reserv_LBL.Text = UsuarioWND.nombreHotel;
            NumeroHab_Reserv_LBL.Text = "";


            this.Habitaciones_Reservacion_DTGV.DataSource = linker.llenarGridHabitacionesSelect(UsuarioWND.nombreHotel);
            this.Cliente_Reservacion_DTGV.DataSource = linker.llenarGridClientesSelect(UsuarioWND.nombreHotel);

            MetodoPag_Reserv_CMB.ValueMember = "ID_MetPago";
            MetodoPag_Reserv_CMB.DisplayMember = "Metodo";
            MetodoPag_Reserv_CMB.DataSource = linker.Fill_Combo(2);

            Servicios_Reserv_CMB.ValueMember = "ID_Servicio";
            Servicios_Reserv_CMB.DisplayMember = "NombreServicio";
            Servicios_Reserv_CMB.DataSource = linker.Fill_Combo(1);


        }
`
```

esto es lo que hay en las funciones llenarGridHabitacionesSelect y llenarGridClientesSelect:

```
    public DataTable llenarGridClientesSelect(string nHotel)
        {
            DataTable _tablaClientes = new DataTable();
            bool isValid = false;
            try
            {
                conectar();
                string qry = "sp_fillTableClienteSelect";
                _comandosql = new SqlCommand(qry, _conexion);
                _comandosql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _comandosql.CommandTimeout = 9000;

                _comandosql.Parameters.Add("@nombreHotel", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = nHotel;

                _adaptador.SelectCommand = _comandosql;
                _adaptador.Fill(_tablaClientes);


                if (_tablaClientes.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    return _tablaClientes;
                }
            }

            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                isValid = false;
                string msg = e.Message;
                MessageBox.Show(msg);
            }
            finally
            {
                desconectar();
                _tablaClientes.Clear();
            }

            return _tablaClientes;
        }
```

ambas funciones son similares, únicamente cambiando los nombres, probé colocando interrupciones en donde mando llamar las funciones, lo raro es que la función se ejecuta normalmente, incluso obtiene el numero de rows que hay en la tabla, pero al salir de la función, devuelve 0 Rows, aparentemente realiza la conexión con éxito, pero la consulta no regresa ningún registro.

Comment: Estas devolviendo la tablaClientes vacía, prueba a quitar _tablaClientes.Clear() en el finally

Comment: Asegúrate que el _tableClientes devuelto tiene las mismas columnas que el DataGridView que va a mostrar dicha tabla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El return _tablaClientes; dentro del try solo realiza el return del try, no del metodo y por lo tanto continua a ejecutarse el finally que se ejecuta no importando si se cacha error o no y por lo tanto estas limpiando la tabla antes de devolverla; al devolverla ya esta limpia (vacia).

En `public DataTable llenarGridClientesSelect(string nHotel)` elimina o comenta _tablaClientes.Clear(); dentro del finally:

```
finally
{ 
   desconectar();
   //_tablaClientes.Clear();
}
```